# Links are not accessible in Android app close reason pop-up

Tags: bug, android-app, close-reasons

Clicking on the *i* button to look at the exact close reason gives this pop-up:

[image: IMG:]

It seems that *here* is a link, yet there is no indication that it is, and tapping around that area has no effect. Long pressing on the words didn't help either.

Apparently the entire *Real questions have answers* sentence is also a link.

I suppose a request for enabling long pressing to copy should be in another question.

Comment: In addition of that, the links on flag/close dialog are not clickable too. Trying to click the link will instead select the reason.